# Assembly x86 - Having troubles with REPE CMPSB

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I made a string-search program in assembly that accepts two strings,
STRING and FIND, with their corresponding sizes (N in the beginning), and I wanted to create a MEMCMP PROC. This MEMCMP retrieves in SI and DI two pointers to strings, and AX to the size of the comparison.
Since "The" is in the beginning of "The quick brown...", I expected the CALL MEMCMP to turn on the ZF, since it kinds of replicates CMP A, B just with two strings. However it does not, and it goes over all string and fails to find the index of "FIND" in "STRING". Can anyone tell me why? **The problem is with MEMCMP, the rest of the code is for showing the usage of MEMCMP**. :

```
DSEG SEGMENT
    STRING  DB "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", 0
    NSTRING DW OFFSET NSTRING - OFFSET STRING
    FIND    DB "The"      
    NFIND   DW OFFSET NFIND - OFFSET FIND
DSEG ENDS

SSEG SEGMENT STACK
    DW 100H DUP(?)
SSEG ENDS

CSEG SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CSEG, DS:DSEG, SS:SSEG ; Assume

    ; Gets 3 parameters from the registers:
    ; (SI = &str1, DI = &str2, AX= size)
    ; And compares them according to size.
    MEMCMP PROC NEAR 
        ; Saving register data.
        PUSHA

        CLD         ; Scan in the forward direction.        
        MOV CX, AX  ; Counter from AX.
        REPE CMPSB  ; Repeating comparison.

        ; Restoring register data.
        POPA
        RET
    MEMCMP ENDP

    MAIN PROC FAR                 ; Creating the main process.
        PUSH DS
        PUSH ES
        MOV AX, 0
        PUSH AX
        MOV AX, DSEG
        MOV DS, AX
        MOV ES, AX
        MOV AX, NFIND             ; Saving NFIND for MEMCMP
        MOV CX, NSTRING           ; Going NSTRING times. 

    FIND_LOOP:                    ; Finding the index of "FIND".
        MOV BX, NSTRING           ; Getting NSTRING.
        SUB BX, CX                ; Getting the current index.
        MOV DX, BX                ; Saving current index.
        MOV SI, OFFSET STRING[BX] ; Setting the SI to the string's current index.
        MOV DI, OFFSET FIND       ; Setting the DI to the start of find.
        CALL MEMCMP               ; Comparing memory.
        JE   END_FIND_LOOP        ; We found a comparison. 
        JNE  CONTINUE_FIND_LOOP   ; We haven't found a comparison.
    CONTINUE_FIND_LOOP:
        CMP  CX, NFIND            ; Comparing CX and NFIND.
        JL   END_FIND_LOOP        ; Found an error, if less than NFIND bytes are left!
        LOOP FIND_LOOP            ; Looping again, finding through another character.

    END_FIND_LOOP:                ; DX now holds the index of the item.
        ; Done! ;
        RET
    MAIN ENDP
CSEG ENDS
END MAIN
```

Comment: You didn't set `ds` and `es`, put after main start: `mov ax,DSEG` `mov ds,ax` `mov es,ax`. Should be visible in emu8086 debugger, that `ds:si` and `es:di` are not pointing to the data you did want to compare.

Comment: @Ped7g I didnt think it was that important to show to stackoverflow, here I added what was in the program.

Comment: Yes, the "string" family of instructions `lods/movs/stos/scans/cmps/...` does use either `ds:si` for source (can be overridden by prefix!), and/or `es:di` for destination (can NOT be overridden by prefix). For SO is important to provide [MCVE], or if you describe only particular detail where you expect problem, then you should describe it extremely verbosely, like including all register values, etc... because usually people tend to expect problems on wrong places, so minimal+working problem demonstration is safest way.

Comment: @Ped7g Sounds important! I added the lines I have in my program. Is there still a problem now?

Comment: Actually, I don't have emu8086, I run the code in head only. So the better you describe your problem, the more likely I will have to emulate less of CPU in head = smaller chance to do a mistake = better chance to spot the real problem. So after setting `ds/es`, what does that code do in debugger? What is wrong about it? In which part do values in registers/flag depart from your original expectations?

Comment: I run the debugger and test out SI and DI's pointers at first. SI points to 0 (STRING is OFFSET 0 in index 0) and DI points to 2F (SIZE of STRING and WORD together). Its all cool. AX is 3, because "The" is 3, and the repetition fails with ZF off. I expected ZF to be on, because "The" of FIND and "The" of STRING are the same in terms of ASCII.

Comment: Now I did read through more of the code... and .. well, hard to say, what it was supposed to do, but it probably doesn't work as you expected. For example `mov si, offset STRING[BX]` is weird (as "not compilable by decent assembler, but as you are in the crap emu8086, you get away with it" weird kind).. by comment I would rather expect `lea si,[STRING + bx]`

Comment: @Ped7g Welp, for some reason LEA fixed the issue.
I am totally confused, haha! It isn't like C that I can disassemble...

Comment: You can actually dissamble it, if you have resulting exe/obj files.. I don't know, I never used emu8086, and more questions I see on SO with it, the less I favour its usage. IMO dosbox + tasm (set to "ideal" mode, not masm compatibility) (or NASM outside of DOS, producing .COM files, I use linux for that) + td (turbo debugger) in the dosbox (if it works) ... would be probably best. Or drop the whole DOS thing and use linux itself, but I miss the 13h graphics mode then, for some pixel fun. (**EDIT:** I believe the emu8086 can also produce listing file during compilation!)

Comment: http://courses.ee.sun.ac.za/OLD/2003/Rekenaarstelsels245/8086_Instruksies/compatibility.html *"Emu8086 does not support the ASSUME directive*" ...

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. I will try using a debugger to the EXE files (Maybe even IDA, makes it easier!)